# How to connect Android to AWS IoT with Paho TLS?

Tags: android, amazon-web-services, ssl, mqtt, paho

Good day,

I'm trying to connect to AWS IoT with android using its SDK, no problem with Android 7 and above. But there's a compatibility problem with below versions. This is detailed in this [Issue](https://github.com/eclipse/paho.mqtt.java/issues/633). I tried using Paho as client library but I haven't been able to figure out how to use those certificates with the Socket factory. Any idea how can I use those certificates with some MQTT Client library?

In the Java SDK was pretty easy to connect and no problem at all, I didn't have to use a keystore for that. Why Android needs to use a keystore to manage those certificates?. Should I install those certificates in the security settings as well?

I have tried using this [wrapper](https://github.com/eurbon/Paho-MQTT-Android-TCP-TLS-WSS-Example). But is quite confuse how it uses those keystores. It throws and exception as it can't create it. Using that wrapper I have been able make some modifications and make it run. But it doesn't trigger anything neither onFail or onSuccess.

This is what I have done:

The class SocketFactory can be found [here](https://github.com/eurbon/Paho-MQTT-Android-TCP-TLS-WSS-Example/blob/master/app/src/main/java/paho/android/mqtt_example/SocketFactory.java)

```java
void MqttSetup() {
        CLIENT = new MqttAndroidClient(getBaseContext(), BROKER, MqttClient.generateClientId());
        MQTT_CONNECTION_OPTIONS = new MqttConnectOptions();

        /**
         * SSL broker requires a certificate to authenticate their connection
         * Certificate can be found in resources folder /res/raw/
         */
        SocketFactory.SocketFactoryOptions socketFactoryOptions = new SocketFactory.SocketFactoryOptions();
        try {
            socketFactoryOptions.withCaInputStream(getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.keystore));
            MQTT_CONNECTION_OPTIONS.setSocketFactory(new SocketFactory(socketFactoryOptions));
        } catch (IOException | NoSuchAlgorithmException | KeyStoreException | CertificateException | KeyManagementException | UnrecoverableKeyException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    void MqttConnect() {
        try {
            final IMqttToken token = CLIENT.connect(MQTT_CONNECTION_OPTIONS);
            token.setActionCallback(new IMqttActionListener() {
                @Override
                public void onSuccess(IMqttToken asyncActionToken) {
                    // We are connected
                    Log.d("mqtt:", "connected, token:" + asyncActionToken.toString());
                    subscribe(TOPIC, (byte) 1);
                }

                @Override
                public void onFailure(IMqttToken asyncActionToken, Throwable exception) {
                    // Something went wrong e.g. connection timeout or firewall problems
                    Log.d("mqtt:", "not connected" + asyncActionToken.toString());
                }
            });
        } catch (MqttException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

When I try to connect to the broker it seems that it can make a connection as it's registered in the Monitor of Aws IoT. But those listeners don't get triggered and there are no thrown exceptions. I thought that I might not be loading those certificates properly.

I have the next files downloaded from Aws IoT (not sure how to bind them in a keystore and access them):

- certificate.pem.crt
- private.pem.key
- public.pem.key

Thanks.

Comment: The MQTT Client of HiveMQ says in its documentation that its supports Android API level 19 and higher. I have currently not the setup to try it out, maybe you could. Link to the documentation where the Android compatibility is mentioned: https://hivemq.github.io/hivemq-mqtt-client/docs/installation/android

Comment: It is mentioned in this issue: https://github.com/eclipse/paho.mqtt.java/issues/633

Comment: The client I mentioned is the HiveMQ MQTT Client. The above issue does not affect it.

Comment: @Rattenfengar connecting Android to Amazon iot thing is nightmare. Did you figured out how you did this ?

Comment: @karticchaudhary yeah, I could make it. I used paho, they released an update and that made the trick back then.